# Linux Mint Network Connection unavailable (not the network, the settings)

Tags: linux-mint

Turned my computer off and on for the first time in a while this morning in the vain hope of clearing up a DNS cache issue, and now besides that I can't access the Network Connection option in Preferences. I can see Network and Network Connection in the Preferences menu, but clicking on either of them does nothing. I have the Network Manager applet in the panel too, but clicking on it just shows an empty black bubble.

Answer (score 0):

Try install network-manager-gnome package running:

> sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome -y

I hope this solve your problem!

Update:

Check if there is the group `netdev` into your system and assign your user to this group.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried your suggestion and was told I already had the newest version of network-manager-gnome.

Comment: @bgates could check the groups that this user belongs?

Comment: Here's something interesting: Through the Settings menu, I can't. In the CLI, `groups` yields `bgates adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare`.